# Total rookie to SiteFinity and .Net development. How to add purchased template- or should I?

Tags: sitefinity

As stated, am totally new to SiteFinity. We use Adobe AEM for our main site (at a university), and I have always been a LAMP shop using custom html, or WordPress for our smaller sites.

Now I am directed to use another department's SiteFinity installation, as well as the template ["Atlantis" from Envato.](https://themeforest.net/item/atlantis-bootstrap-multipurpose-responsive-theme/4731292)

Im thinking I would create a .net project, import the template into that, create .master page, etc, then upload to SiteFinity.

Am I correct? Is this possible? Is it recommended? Is there a tutorial?

My choice would be a similar WordPress template, or at the very least an html site with PHP/Maria (which is what we have done in the past).

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible to incorporate any html into a Sitefinity web site.

You can also use either classic WebForms or MVC (the preferred approach).

There is plenty of documentation, maybe you can start here:

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/overview-page-templates